# Remove embed exe from pdf?

Tags: pdf, embed, exe

Is there a way to check/remove an exe that is embedded inside a pdf file? (old version of adobe reader exploit)

If I update my adobe reader to the latest version then this isn't necessary? I've heard that it cover this exploit.

Answer (score 0):

Those exe files are invoked from a `Launch` action.

If you're a developer (which you are, otherwise you wouldn't be on SO), then you can use this code snippet to remove those Launch actions from your PDFs: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=233

The code sample actually replaces the `Launch` action with a JavaScript `alert`.

For a C# version, see http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH13